# Cgroups blkio: should I limit reads and writes by bps or iops?

Tags: linux

I need to reduce the disk i/o of a process, and I'm trying to figure out whether it makes the most sense to do so using bps or iops. Are there particular circumstances which would favor one option over the other?

Edited in response to comments:
The process in question is a routine maintenance script that, among other things, performs log rotation. (This is the i/o intensive part of the script.) When it is running, the server is bogged down, particularly database queries are unable to complete. Essentially, the server is unable to serve visitors for a short period of time every day.

Comment: What's the real issue (in order to avoid this being an [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info))? Why does the disk I/O of the process need to be reduced?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: @Bintz: It seems like asking: should I limit network bandwidth by bps or pps?

Comment: This seems like a fair analogy to me, but does not provide me with an answer. Should I limit network bandwidth by bps or pps?

Comment: I am inclined to say that the answer is "iops", because bps is a factor of "iops x block size", and block size can vary. Meanwhile the bottleneck is actually iops. Therefore, if I limit by iops, the server should still be able to perform i/o operations, regardless of how much data is being moved.

Comment: Are you interested in fixing the root issue of your server being unable to handle routine log rotation? I mean, that's a bad sign for modern equipment. You could go down the cgroup approach, but I think that's a poor fix. Use IOPS.

Comment: Thank you. I set it up this way yesterday, and the maintenance script ran without a hitch.

Comment: The issue with fixing the log rotation is that it is done as part of maintenance scripts that come with the Plesk control panel that I have on the server. I'm not interested in fixing their badly designed software for them. The Plesk software is satisfactory in other regards (plus we can't switch to a different option for a variety of other reasons), so the cgroups solution is reasonable.